# Inheriting fields from a parent table olap cube

Tags: olap, ssas, olap-cube, measure

I have an OLAP cube containing a numeric measure that represent a foreign key against a parent table. I would like display the 'name' field from the parent table instead of the measure in my reports. it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a dimension based on this table? If you have one than it should work by design (though not as a measure but as a dimension attribute member name)
If you do not have a dimension that that information (name attribute) is not included in the cube.

Also consider that a typical MDX query is not on the granularity level of the fact table, so for a specific coordinate, say Year 2007 in a fact table that contains monthly data there would probably be n-values in that measure and the default behavior is to aggregate that measure using some of the available aggregation formulas.
If on the other hand it was a dimension key then you could display the count of fact records in Year 2007, or different dimension members that crossjoin with Year 2007 in the fact table.

Could you be more specific in your question?

Regards,
Hrvoje